# Ruby & Rails installation on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I used railstutorial.org to install the latest version of ruby and the latest version of rails on my machine.

at the end of the installation I checked

```
ruby -v ==> 1.9.2 (great)
rails -v ==> 3.0.1 (great)
```

this morning I opened up terminal

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [universal-darwin9.0]
rails -v
Rails 1.2.6
```

what happened?

Comment: Sounds like a PATH problem to me.

Answer (score 6):

My advice for people who are installing ruby is to use [RVM](https://rvm.io). It makes managing your ruby versions and gem versions really simple and you can install multiple ruby versions side by side.

Comment: +1. Agreed, RVM is THE way to go. RVM has SO many advantages, including managing gems using "gemsets", allowing easy testing of code against multiple versions of Ruby, and easily blowing a Ruby away if you want to.

Comment: I did use RVM to install.  now when i try to run rvm commands like
rvm system

i get 'rvm: command not found

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions?  There's a whole post install section: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: "The first time you install RVM, you must put the following line into your profile at the very end, after all path loads etc:"

where can I find my profile?  (apologies if this question is sounds stupid, i'm new to the programming)

Comment: got it.  i also needed to add source ~/.bashrc at the top of my profile files, as these were the onyl lines.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this post:
http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/12/20/how-do-i-keep-multiple-ruby-projects-separate/

Answer (score 0):

With many unix variants, you are likely to have multiple versions of Ruby--particularly if you installed Ruby 1.9 and the system already had 1.8 installed.  Essentially, the 1.8 version of Ruby has a higher precedence in your PATH than the 1.9 version.  The Ruby Gems command keeps the libraries separate between 1.8 and 1.9 so that the platform will be reasonably stable.

To correct the problem, you have to find where ruby 1.9 is installed.  Once you do that, you'll need to override your PATH variable.  Assuming 1.9 is installed in the path: `/opt/ruby-1.9.2`, you will need to set your PATH like this:

```
PATH=/opt/ruby-1.9.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

To make the path respect what you want every time, add that to your `~/.profile` file (create it if necessary).  Once the path has been set, it sould be able to find the correct version of Rails again.

Comment: My mistake.  I will edit appropriately.  It's this switching from Unix to Windows and back that drives me nuts

Comment: Or better yet, use RVM and let it handle all the hassles.

Comment: Haven't used RVM, but it's not a difficult fix to adjust the path.  I think it helps to understand how the system works to be more effective troubleshooting when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cinderalla](http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/) to the whole ruby/rvm/mysql/redis/git/... stack set up properly. Cinderella installs everything in `~/Developer` and fixes up your `PATH` as well. I had some issues with a corrupt `git` mirror last time I used Cinderalla though so YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot say for certain because I cannot debug you OSX machine from here, however, I had a very similar occurrence. The problem was caused because I had installed ruby and then rails on my machine using sudo or from the root account. Then when I discovered rvm I installed everything in my user account.  When I logged off and back in I appeared to lose everything.  I was pulling out my hair. I was pissed that I was going to have to reinstall everything again... when I found the magic.

from the command line execute the command:

```
rvm list
```

you'll see that your new version of ruby is there. you'll also notice the tokens that indicate that it is just a normal version. It is not current or default. (see it yet)

Now if you run the command:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

then every time you login/off and restart your machine your user account will default to that version of ruby and all of the gems that you installed against that version.